# Use JMSSerializer groups to serialize object with or without the inline option

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'd like to have two different representations for the same entity using the PHP library JMSSerializer, which can easily be achieved by its groups feature.

The problem is that I have one representation where the properties of a sub object are inlined, and once they are not. It would be nice if it works somehow like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serializer>
    <class name="SomeEntity">
        <property name="structure" type="SomeOtherEntity" groups="group1" inline="true"/>
        <property name="structure" type="SomeOtherEntity" groups="group2"/>
    </class>
</serializer>
```

What I wanted to accomplish this way, was that `SomeEntity` could be serialized using `group1` with `SomeOtherEntity` being inlined, and with `group2` if `SomeOtherEntity` should not be inlined, but that doesn't seem to work (I guess the name attribute is kind of unique).

A solution would be to introduce another method in combination with a `VirtualProperty`, but then I would have to touch the class, which I would prefer to avoid, since it is a pure serialization issue.

Any better ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Basically for legacy reasons. The idea is not to have both of them, but only one of both definitions, based on which serialization groups are passed when serializing the object. I need a representation where the object is contained in its own property, and one in which it doesn't (that's what inline is doing).

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment after I realized your question had a good point. ;)

Comment: Isn't this something a handler can do? http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers I will write an answer based on this.

Comment: Hm, you are right, with some additional logic this might be possible... Probably the way to go, although I leave the question open, in case there is somebody having a better solution :-)

Comment: And what I don't like about handlers is that they are always bound to a certain format :-/ It's also a bit annoying that you can't use `addData` on the visitor, if it is serialized using XML.

Comment: As you say about the virtualProperties it can be a solution, but you don't need to touch the class, you can basically make 2 virtual properties one with inline and other without it, and put them in different groups, and the original property you can make it expose false.

Comment: But the virtual property needs a method, which it calls. If this method does not exist yet, the class has to be touched, or am I missing something?

Comment: Inherit the class and add the method in the child class. This way you avoid touching the parent class. It's also the quickest solution.